# Why wont Racing game break when I reach 0 in python

Tags: python

Not sure about the issue. I have the game run a constant random num for 2 runners, but it doesn't break when my runner reaches 0. I've tried flipping around the `if Cheetah and Rabbit == 0`, but it's not working. The numbers just go into the negative

```
import time
import random

Cheetah = 222
Rabbit = 222

for i in range(222):
    a = random.randint(4, 10)
    if Cheetah == 0:
        print("Cheetah Wins!")
        break
    if a == 4:
        Cheetah = Cheetah - 4
        print(Cheetah, "Cheetah")
    elif a == 5:
        Cheetah = Cheetah - 5
        print(Cheetah, "Cheetah")
    elif a == 6:
        Cheetah = Cheetah - 6
        print(Cheetah, "Cheetah")
    elif a == 7:
        Cheetah = Cheetah - 7
        print(Cheetah, "Cheetah")
    elif a == 8:
        Cheetah = Cheetah - 8
        print(Cheetah, "Cheetah")
    elif a == 9:
        Cheetah = Cheetah - 9
        print(Cheetah, "Cheetah")
    elif a == 10:
        Cheetah = Cheetah - 10
        print(Cheetah, "Cheetah")

    b = random.randint(3, 10)
    if Rabbit == 0:
        print("Rabbit Wins")
        break
    if b == 3:
        Rabbit = Rabbit - 3
        print(Rabbit, "Rabbit")
    elif b == 4:
        Rabbit = Rabbit - 4
        print(Rabbit, "Rabbit")
    elif b == 5:
        Rabbit = Rabbit - 5
        print(Rabbit, "Rabbit")
    elif b == 6:
        Rabbit = Rabbit - 6
        print(Rabbit, "Rabbit")
    elif b == 7:
        Rabbit = Rabbit - 7
        print(Rabbit, "Rabbit")
    elif b == 8:
        Rabbit = Rabbit - 8
        print(Rabbit, "Rabbit")
    elif b == 9:
        Rabbit = Rabbit - 9
        print(Rabbit, "Rabbit")
    elif b == 10:
        Rabbit = Rabbit - 10
        print(Rabbit, "Rabbit")
```

Comment: Because you are checking if Rabbit or Cheetah are *exactly* `0`

Comment: All those `if .. elif ...` could be changed and simplified by quite a lot. Like `if a >= 4 and a <= 10: Cheetah = Cheetah - a; print(Cheetah, "Cheetah")`

Comment: Did you mean: `if Cheetah <= 0:`?

Comment: Good answers. I honestly don't know the mose efficient ways of doing things. I'm trying to start with simple simulations to start

Answer (score 3):

This is a very specific condition:

```
if Cheetah == 0:
```

What happens if `Cheetah` equals `1` and `a` equals `4`?:

```
Cheetah = Cheetah - 4
```

Now `Cheetah` equals `-3`.  And since you only ever subtract from it, it will *never* equal `0`.

Instead of checking whether the value is *exactly zero*, check if it's anything less than one:

```
if Cheetah < 1:
```

That way it will be satisfied if it's `0` or anything negative.

Answer (score 2):

You have to compare it with `<=`. Also those if-Statements are obsolete. You can shorten the code massively by doing this:

```
import time
import random

Cheetah = 222
Rabbit = 222

for i in range(222):
    a = random.randint(4, 10)
    Cheetah = Cheetah - a
    print(Cheetah, "Cheetah")

    b = random.randint(3, 10)
    Rabbit = Rabbit - b
    print(Rabbit, "Rabbit")
    
    if Cheetah <= 0:
        print("Cheetah Wins!")
        break
    
    if Rabbit <= 0:
        print("Rabbit Wins")
        break
```